# React changing the background color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

after learning javascript, I started to learn React and I'm not quite sure how DOM manipulation works in React, for example, I want to change the background colour in React, is it similar to Javascript or it's totally something else?

````
   const onClick = () =>{
       document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'Dodgerblue';
   }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClick}>Change background Color</button>
    </div>
  )
}```
````

Comment: Yes, this will work.

Comment: @New coder while it would work, it defeats the purpose of using React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your case scenario is working fine because you are selecting an element inside a function, the issue that can happen in React is if you try to select an element that is *about to be rendered, (but isn't yet rendered)* will return `null` value because the selector method won't return any element/node.

Example code:

```
...
  const selectText = document.getElementById("testDOM");
  const faultyFunction = () => {
    selectText.style.color = "red";
  } //Calling this function throws TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')


  const onClick = () =>{
    const selectText = document.getElementById("testDOM");
    selectText.style.color = "red";
   } //This works as expected,
    //as the function is selecting an element once the DOM has been rendered

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClick}>Change Text Color</button>
      <br/>
      <button onClick={faultyFunction}>Faulty Button</button>
      <p id="testDOM">Random Text</p>
    </div>
  )
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it will because react is based on JavaScript and html so this should work fine